# Xamarin serial port comms support

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere in their docs.

We are considering using Xamarin for an business app that will need to interface over RS232 with an external device. The first version will be on Desktop, but later we want to move to an Android Tablet, which is why we are considering Xamarin.

**Is comms access possible through Xamarin on Windows? What about Android?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a serial port on the Android device and if you can use that with a native (Java) app, you will be able to use it with Xamarin.Android. All native API can be bound if not available.
A quick googling shows me there seems to be serial port third party API: http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/

A reference how to do bindings can be found here: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)